# Select the First Page Header of the second section using Interop.Word in C#

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop

I want to select the First Page Header of the second section in my Word document, using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word (Microsoft Word 12.0 Object Library) in C#.

This is the code that is running:

```
Range headerRange = oDoc.Sections[2].Headers[WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterFirstPage].Range;
headerRange.Select();
```

It is selecting the First Page Header of the first section. I want to select the First Page Header of the second section to unlink it from the header of the first section and make it look different.

For some more input I loop over some information that I add to the document and add a new section between each loop with this code:

```
object oEndOfDoc = @"\endofdoc";
oDoc.Bookmarks.get_Item(ref oEndOfDoc).Range.InsertBreak(WdBreakType.wdSectionBreakNextPage);
```

Comment: Is the header is the first text in the document?\

Comment: No, I fill the section with content first and then I try add the header

Comment: I would like to understand properly: what is the problem: managing the text of header, or, have the text of header in hand and don't know how to 'stick' it to a particular section?

Comment: I need to unlink the second section's First Page Header to the first one's. Then add content to the second section's First Page Header, so that the first section's First Page Header will remain the way it is

Comment: And where do you get stuck? finding the second place where the first page header is exists?

Comment: Because it's always targeting the **first** section's First Page Header, even though I'm trying to point out the **second** section. So I'm handling the wrong header basically (the content lands in the wrong header and so on)

Comment: Did you try to manage `Sections[3]` header? may it returns the second section?

Comment: Yeah I tried that. And the header I get is still the one in the first section

Comment: Sound like this is not the way to get a header of a section. Why do you try to get `WdHeaderFooterIndex.wdHeaderFooterFirstPage`? this is probably refers to the first page and then you get the header of first section which located in the first page.

Comment: Yeah, that thought has struck me as well. I use that one because it is a "First Page Header", you know the one where you can get a different first page. The other options I have are just the regular headers. And it seems to be linked by default, so when I create a new section, it gets the same headers and footers as on the first page in the section before. Manually I can just unlink it to the one before and change it, but it's still a "First Page Header", which is not linked to the regular ones that follows

Comment: If you manage to solve the issue, please post it as an answer and notify me. Thanks.